# Problem with the error: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

Hey I am new to programming with python and just want that this code printing out every number in range 0 and 100 that has the digit 9 in it, but I always get this message: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    if 9 in i:
        print(i)
```

So what I expect is that my code will return:

> 9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99

Comment: `i != str(i)` You are confusing a number and its string representation. `9 in i` is nonsensical since a number is not a container of digits. On the other hand, `'9' in str(i)` makes perfect sense.

Comment: Ok thanks now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, 100): 
    if 9 in i:
        print(i)
```

The line

```
if 9 in i:
```

will work if i is a list or an array since your iterator returns only one value which is int( int is not iterable), it fails. A simpler way to do this is

> ```
> for i in range(0, 100): 
>     if "9" in str(i):
>         print(i)
> ```

What's happening here is that you are converting the int to string( which is an array of characters), no you can use the "in" method.